# Android ProgressDialog Error When Resuming an Activity

Tags: java, android

When I start a `ProgressDialog` in my `Activity`, everything works correctly.
After I press the back button on the dialog to resume the `Activity`, I receive an error: "Unable to add window token android.BindeProxy@b6483550 is not valid, is your activity running?".
Is there a way to close the `ProgressDialog` when I want to finish this `Activity` and then show it again next time I start this `Activity`?

My Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_view);
    mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
    SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
    mLoginButton.init(this, mFacebook);
}

@Override
public void onResume () {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause () {
    super.onPause();
}

public class SampleAuthListener implements AuthListener {

    public void onAuthSucceed() {
        TheGaffer.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TheGaffer.this, "Loading", "Please wait...");
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "name,id");
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", params, new LoginRequestListener());
    }

    public void onAuthFail(String error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public class LoginRequestListener implements RequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String fbid = json.getString("id");
            jsonObjSend.put("fbid", json.getString("id"));
            jsonObjSend.put("username", json.getString("name"));
            jsonObjSend.put("playerPhoto", "http://graph.facebook.com/"+ json.getString("id") +"/picture");
            HttpClient.SendHttpPost("/user_profiles/registerUser", jsonObjSend);
            TheGaffer.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (TheGaffer.this.progressDialog != null) {
                        TheGaffer.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TheGaffer.this, TeamActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("fbid", fbid);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, final Object state) {
        Log.e("Facebook", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                        final Object state) {
        Log.e("Facebook", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onIOException(IOException e, final Object state) {
        Log.e("Facebook", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                        final Object state) {
        Log.e("Facebook", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
     {
        TheGaffer.this.progressDialog = null;
        finish();
        return true;
     }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Comment: the problem still exist, i think maybe because i called finish()

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

prgDialog.dismiss();

when you want to dismiss it. Then this error will not be there

Answer (score 0):

It causes because progress dialog tried to show itself on to an Activity which has already been closed.
Check for `isFinished()` before you show a dialog, progress bar.